# How to import csv files selected by user to database

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

I wonder how i can import csv files that selected by user to database using php.

is there any practical way on this ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a function for this: [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). You'll still have to write the loop and the code that inserts rows into the database however.

```
$in = fopen('filename.csv', 'r');
while (($row = fgetcsv($in, 10000, ',')) !== false) {
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO ....");
}
fclose($in);
```

Comment: yeah but how can i use it to selected file by user, i guess i need to upload file first then use this function then delete file ?

Comment: Use PHP's support for uploading files. See http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php and other tutorials.