# How to upload CSV/excel file to MySql using PHP with column name not index number?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, file-upload

My code is working good. But there is a little issue like my csv file column numbers keeps changing by time. And it's not possible to change the index number in my code every time. So I have found a solution like I can read csv by column name not number.  How can I fetch record of csv file based on the column name behalf of the Column Number? 
Thanks in advance.

```
 if ($_POST["upload"] == "freight") {
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $c = 0;
        $branch=$_POST["freight"];

        while (($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 3000000, ",")) !== false) {
            $invoice_number = $filesop[3];
            $freaight3 = $filesop[12];

            $freaight2 = substr($freaight3, 0, -2);
            if($freaight2=="")
            {
                $freaight2=0;
            }
            $with_tax = $filesop[10];
            $with_tax2 = substr($with_tax, 0, -2);
            $Invoice_Number = $branch."_" .$invoice_number;
            $update_freaight = "UPDATE xyz SET `Total_Freight`=" . $freaight2 . ",`Value_With_Tax`='" . $with_tax2 . "' where `Invoice_Number`='" . $Invoice_Number . "'";
          //   echo $update_freaight;
            $update = mysqli_query($con, $update_freaight);
        }
        if ($update) {
            $massage = "You database has imported successfully. You have inserted " . $c . " recoreds";
        } else {
            $massage = "Sorry! There is some problem.";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import csv files selected by user to database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611017/how-to-import-csv-files-selected-by-user-to-database)

Comment: @MohsenShakibafar I have already mention in my question that problem is not to upload the csv file. By this code also I am able to upload data to database but i want to upload it by the column name  not the column number. And (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611017/how-to-import-csv-files-selected-by-user-to-database) is not the same question as i asked.

Answer (score 0):

Finally by 11 hours search I did it by my own. Not a right way but yeah its logically right!.

```
   $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file("$file",FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
            $keys = array_shift($csv);
            for($i=0;$i<=sizeof($keys);$i++)
            {
                $name=$keys[$i];
                if($name=="xyz") {
                    $xyz = $i;
                    continue;
                }
               else if($name=="abc") {
                    $abc = $i;
                    continue;
                }
              else if($name=="tax") {
                    $tax = $i;
                    continue;
                }
}

if ($_POST["upload"] == "freight") {
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $c = 0;
        $branch=$_POST["freight"];

        while (($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 3000000, ",")) !== false) {
            $xyz = $filesop[$xyz];
            $abc = $filesop[$abc];

            $freaight2 = substr($abc, 0, -2);
            if($freaight2=="")
            {
                $freaight2=0;
            }
            $with_tax = $filesop[$tax];
            $with_tax2 = substr($with_tax, 0, -2);
            $Invoice_Number = $branch."_" .$invoice_number;
            $update_freaight = "UPDATE xyz SET `Total_Freight`=" . $freaight2 . ",`Value_With_Tax`='" . $with_tax2 . "' where `Invoice_Number`='" . $Invoice_Number . "'";
          //   echo $update_freaight;
            $update = mysqli_query($con, $update_freaight);
        }
        if ($update) {
            $massage = "You database has imported successfully. You have inserted " . $c . " recoreds";
        } else {
            $massage = "Sorry! There is some problem.";
        }

    }
```